# Passing a method data to other method in same Activity

Tags: json, android-studio, android-intent

I am newbie to Android Studio and I am making my final year project.

I made a QR code scanner that can retrieve data from HTTP using Rest API.

**My question is:** I need to send all the JSON data to other activity, based on my research I need to put intent on my button, because of that I need to pass my JsonRequest data to `Btn_BuyClicked` method so I can send all those to next activity.

I used AndroidHive MovieTickets so Im not changing so much coding.

Please help me. Thank you.

```
public class TicketResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = TicketResultActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Button btnBuy;
private ImageView imgPoster;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private TicketView ticketView;
private TextView txtDirector;
private TextView txtYear_created;
private TextView txtError;
private TextView txtType_powder;
private TextView txtApa_number;
private TextView txtLocation;
private TextView txtDate_expired;

private Button signOut;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

private class Movie {
    String director;
    String year_created;
    String type_powder;
    @SerializedName("released")
    boolean isReleased;
    String apa_number;
    String poster;
    String location;
    String date_expired;

    private Movie() {
    }

    public String getApa_number() {
        return this.apa_number;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return this.director;
    }

    public String getPoster() {
        return this.poster;
    }

    public String getYear_created() {
        return this.year_created;
    }

    public String getType_powder() {
        return this.type_powder;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    public String getDate_expired() {
        return this.date_expired;
    }

    public boolean isReleased() {
        return this.isReleased;
    }
}

NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
private static final int uniqueID = 250298;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticket_result);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    this.txtApa_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apa_number);
    this.txtDirector = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.director);
    this.txtYear_created = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.year_created);
    this.txtLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    this.txtDate_expired = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_expired);
    this.imgPoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.poster);
    this.txtType_powder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_powder);
    this.btnBuy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);
    this.imgPoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.poster);
    this.txtError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_error);
    this.ticketView = (TicketView) findViewById(R.id.layout_ticket);
    this.progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    String barcode = getIntent().getStringExtra("code");
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(barcode)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Barcode is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
    searchBarcode(barcode);

}




public void btn_buyClicked(View view) {

    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.qrcode);
    notification.setTicker("This is the ticker");
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setContentTitle("Fire Extinguisher Scanner");



    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test.class);
    startActivity(new Intent(TicketResultActivity.this, Test.class));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());


}


private void searchBarcode(String barcode) {
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,  barcode, null, new Listener<JSONObject>() {
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e(TicketResultActivity.TAG, "Ticket response: " + response.toString());
            if (response.has("error")) {
                TicketResultActivity.this.showNoTicket();
            } else {
                TicketResultActivity.this.renderMovie(response);

            }
        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TicketResultActivity.TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            TicketResultActivity.this.showNoTicket();
        }
    }));
}

private void showNoTicket() {
    this.txtError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    this.ticketView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}



public void renderMovie(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        Movie movie = (Movie) new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Movie.class);
        if (movie != null) {
            this.txtApa_number.setText(movie.getApa_number());
            this.txtDirector.setText(movie.getDirector());
            this.txtYear_created.setText(movie.getYear_created());
            this.txtType_powder.setText(movie.getType_powder());
            this.txtDate_expired.setText(BuildConfig.FLAVOR + movie.getDate_expired());
            this.txtLocation.setText(movie.getLocation());
            Glide.with(this).load(movie.getPoster()).into(this.imgPoster);
            notification.setContentText("Fire Extinguisher "+ movie.getApa_number()+"successfully remind!");


            if (movie.isReleased()) {
                this.btnBuy.setText(getString(R.string.btn_buy_now));
                this.btnBuy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            } else {
                this.btnBuy.setText(getString(R.string.btn_buy_now));
                this.btnBuy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            }
            this.ticketView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        showNoTicket();
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "JSON Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        showNoTicket();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred. Check your LogCat for full report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        showNoTicket();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred. Check your LogCat for full report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is my TicketResultActivity.java class **UPDATED CODE**

```
 private static class Movie implements Parcelable {
    String director;
    String year_created;
    String type_powder;
    @SerializedName("released")
    boolean isReleased;
    String apa_number;
    String poster;
    String location;
    String date_expired;

    public Movie() {

    }


    public Movie(Parcel in) {
        director = in.readString();
        year_created = in.readString();
        type_powder = in.readString();
        isReleased = in.readByte() != 0;
        apa_number = in.readString();
        poster = in.readString();
        location = in.readString();
        date_expired = in.readString();
    }


    public String getApa_number(){
        return this.apa_number;
    }

    public String getYear_created() {
        return year_created;
    }

    public String getType_powder() {
        return type_powder;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public String getPoster() {
        return poster;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public boolean isReleased() {
        return isReleased;
    }

    public String getDate_expired() {
        return date_expired;
    }

    public void setApa_number(String apa_number){
        this.apa_number = apa_number;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(director);
        dest.writeString(year_created);
        dest.writeString(type_powder);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (isReleased ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeString(apa_number);
        dest.writeString(poster);
        dest.writeString(location);
        dest.writeString(date_expired);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Movie(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movie[size];
        }
    };


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }


}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticket_result);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    this.txtApa_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apa_number);
    this.txtDirector = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.director);
    this.txtYear_created = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.year_created);
    this.txtLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    this.txtDate_expired = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_expired);
    this.imgPoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.poster);
    this.txtType_powder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_powder);
    this.btnBuy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);
    this.imgPoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.poster);
    this.txtError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_error);
    this.ticketView = (TicketView) findViewById(R.id.layout_ticket);
    this.progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    String barcode = getIntent().getStringExtra("code");
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(barcode)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Barcode is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
    searchBarcode(barcode);
}




public void btn_buyClicked(View view) {


    // In activity or fragment
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setApa_number("xyz");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test.class);
    intent.putExtra("parcel_data", movie);
    startActivity(intent);

}


private void searchBarcode(String barcode) {
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,  barcode, null, new Listener<JSONObject>() {
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e(TicketResultActivity.TAG, "Ticket response: " + response.toString());
            if (response.has("error")) {
                TicketResultActivity.this.showNoTicket();
            } else {
                TicketResultActivity.this.renderMovie(response);

            }
        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TicketResultActivity.TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            TicketResultActivity.this.showNoTicket();
        }
    }));
}

private void showNoTicket() {
    this.txtError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    this.ticketView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}



public void renderMovie(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        Movie movie = (Movie) new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Movie.class);
        if (movie != null) {
            this.txtApa_number.setText(movie.getApa_number());
            this.txtDirector.setText(movie.getDirector());
            this.txtYear_created.setText(movie.getYear_created());
            this.txtType_powder.setText(movie.getType_powder());
            this.txtDate_expired.setText(BuildConfig.FLAVOR + movie.getDate_expired());
            this.txtLocation.setText(movie.getLocation());
            Glide.with(this).load(movie.getPoster()).into(this.imgPoster);


            if (movie.isReleased()) {
                this.btnBuy.setText(getString(R.string.btn_buy_now));
                this.btnBuy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            } else {
                this.btnBuy.setText(getString(R.string.btn_buy_now));
                this.btnBuy.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            }
            this.ticketView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        showNoTicket();
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "JSON Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        showNoTicket();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred. Check your LogCat for full report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        showNoTicket();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred. Check your LogCat for full report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is **Test.java Class**

```
public class Test extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Movie movie = (Movie) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("parcel_data");
        String apa_number = movie.getApa_number();

        TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView1.setText(apa_number);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Use Parcelable is an interface. A class who implements Parcelable can write to and read from a Parcel.
        You need to follow 3 points to create a Parcelable class.
        A Class must implement Parcelable interface
        A Class must have a non-null static field CREATOR of a type that implements Parcelable.Creator interface.
        Override writeToParcel method and write member variable in Parcel. Make sure to read variables in the same sequence in which they are written in Parcel. Order of read and write matters.


        private class Movie implements Parcelable{
            String director;
            String year_created;
            String type_powder;
            @SerializedName("released")
            boolean isReleased;
            String apa_number;
            String poster;
            String location;
            String date_expired;

    public Movie() {

    }

            // In constructor you will read the variables from Parcel. Make sure to read them in the same sequence in which you have written them in Parcel.
        public Movie(Parcel in) {
        director = in.readString();
        year_created = in.readString();
        release_date = in.readString();
        poster = in.readString();
        }

            public String getApa_number() {
                return this.apa_number;
            }

             public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

        // This is where you will write your member variables in Parcel. Here you can write in any order. It is not necessary to write all members in Parcel.
        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // Write data in any order
        dest.writeString(director);
        dest.writeString(year_created);
        dest.writeString(release_date);
        dest.writeString(poster);
        }

        // This is to de-serialize the object
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>(){
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Movie(in);
        }

        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Movie[size];
        }
        };
        }

        Now you can pass a Parcelable object using Intent.

        // In activity or fragment
        Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.setDirector("xyz");
// now you can set all values like :year created, is released whatever.
        // using context and next component class to create intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
        // using putExtra(String key, Parcelable value) method
        intent.putExtra(“parcel_data”, movie);
        startActivity(intent);

        You can access this data in NextActivity –

        public class NextActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Using getParcelableExtra(String key) method
        Movie movie = (Movie) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("parcel_data");
           String director = movie.getDirector();
        }
        }
```

Comment: But I got an error on Movie movie = new Movie(); saying that Movie(Parcel) in Movie can not be applied to (). I put this in btn_BuyClicked. Maybe I was wrong, I hope you can correct me. Thank you I appreciated a lot.

Comment: Just create a default constructor in a Movie Class, i have changed the code, please look into it.

Comment: Thanks, but why still I cant retrieve my data on NextActivity, i try to put String apa_number = movie.getApa_number; but getApa_number turns red. Im really sorry, I really new with this Parcelable.

Comment: Thank you sir, I appreciated a lot. Tell me if you already complete. Thank you so much!

Comment: No wyou can check the updated code, as You can see that whenever we create an object of Movie class, we need to set values as well like i did setDirector() in aboive code.Now try with this one, if you still faces any issues let me know.

Comment: Thank you but I still face the same issues where String director = movie.getDirector(); which is getDirector is still on red. Maybe on NextActivity i should declare something?

Comment: Now you can checked updated code above. Thank you sir I appreciated.

Comment: From update code : remove static from Movie class, It should be like public class Movie implements Parceable{ and as of just commment searchBarcode(barcode); from onCreate method of activity, then run the code and check whether second activity able to received data or not.

Comment: Sir, I updated like how u ask and still facing the same issues. I tried to run and they give Compilation failed because of the error. Im sorry if I put you on trouble. Maybe we can chat on other platform?

Comment: I deleted the static from Movie class but there got an error after i delete which is return new Movie(in); in public Movie createFromParcel saying that cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Nevermind, i used SharedPreferences instead of parcelable. I have to submit my project by next week,  so i already finished. thank you for your help before this. i appreciated a lot sir :D

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to send data from one activity to another activity. If you Have `Primitive` or `Json string` type data then you can directly put that data into the intent.

But if in case you have Model class and you need to pass it. Then you have two ways:

1. [Serializable](https://medium.com/@kkunalandroid/serializable-in-android-with-example-38eb8b7334ea)
2. [Parcelable](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/05/android-parcelable-tutorial-list-class-2.html)

**But Android recommend to use Parcelable.**

You can also add plugin to android studio to generate the parcelable code.